# Projectile does not show all files in project

Tags: git, projectile

After visiting a file that is part of a git repository, Projectile acknowledges the existence of my git repository as a project, but it only lists one file (the current file) as being part of the project.  As I visit other files in the project, they become part of the project one at a time.

**How do I create projects in Projectile so that they are immediately aware of *all* files in the project?**

All of the tutorials that I have found so far assume that you are visiting a file within an existing project, and that Projectile knows what files that project contains.

---

#### Update

When I set up Projectile I took the following suggestion in the Projectile documentation:

> #### Caching
>
> Since indexing a big project is not exactly quick (especially in Emacs
> Lisp), Projectile supports caching of the project's files. The caching
> is enabled by default whenever native indexing is enabled.
>
> To enable caching unconditionally use this snippet of code:
>
> `(setq projectile-enable-caching t)`

Since I will occasionally be navigating some large projects, I added this to my init file hoping that it would give me a performance boost.  I do not know how Projectile manages its caching, but at the time I assumed that the first time I visited a project, the project tree would be explored, and the cache would be populated with all of the project files. It appears that my assumption was wrong.

After I set `projectile-enable-caching` to `nil`, Projectile was able to find all of the files in my project.  Thanks to [alexurba's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2169/93) and follow-up comments, I was able to find the problem.

Comment: This question is far too broad, and should be closed. It is not a good candidate for SE. Please pose a specific question about a single, specific problem you are having. Provide contextual info as needed for the specific problem.

Comment: I think it is a good question that just has too much backstory. I think if it were refocused on this line: "How do I set up projects in Projectile so that they are immediately aware of all files in the project.", it would be good.

Comment: @JordonBiondo: The more focused it is, the more useful (for SE) it is. Certainly one could aim for a minimal degree of focus, so that it would not be closed/closable. But one should be able to do even better than that. I'm guessing that there are probably 3 or 4 good questions in there, somewhere, and everyone would benefit if they were posed separately, in a focused way.

Comment: Which platform are you using (Windows, Mac, Linux)?  The indexing of project files seems to be implemented platform dependently.

Comment: I am testing this on Linux (RHEL 6.5), but I would like to be able to use it on all platforms.

Comment: Your update edit has saved my sanity. I was so confused about why I was only seeing files I had already visited in projectile, instead of all files in a project. I found it very annoying but put up with it. I must have turned on projectile-enable-caching accidentally at some point. Thanks for posting the update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once activated, `projectile` works out-of-the-box for git projects.  To activate include

```
(projectile-global-mode)
```

in your Emacs configuration (or start `projectile-mode`) manually.

Then `projectile-find-file` (default key binding is `C-c p f`) works just like `find-file`, but will act on all files in the subdirectories of the project's main directory (where the `.git` directory is).

If you want to avoid git, you can alternatively create a file `.projectile` in the project root.  This will have the same effect and can be used to ignore certain files or directories (similar to `.gitignore`).

Much more info can be found on the [project's github page](http://batsov.com/projectile) (which is too long a read, either).  I especially recommend to read the sections about `Ido` and `helm`.

#### Edit:

Check the value of `projectile-indexing-method`. On Linux this should be `alien`, and the value of `projectile-enable-caching` should be `nil`.

Comment: This is exactly the part that is not working for me.  When I run `projectile-find-file`, the only files listed are the ones that I have already visited, even though the project directory contains many more.

Comment: @nispio, on the project page it mentions different indexing and caching methods.  Can you check the value of `projectile-indexing-method` (`C-h v projectile-indexing-method`)?  On Linux this should be `alien`.

Comment: And `projectile-enable-caching` should be `nil`.

Comment: You found it. I set `projectile-enable-caching` to `nil` and it started working how I expect.  Knowing that, I was able to set it back to `t` and then use `C-u C-c p f` to invalidate the cache for `projectile-find-file` and that is also working.  I'm confused why I need to invalidate the cache if the project has never been cached before, but I will save that for another question, perhaps.

Comment: Great that it works.  Though, I am not sure what will happen under Windows where 'alien' indexing is not available.  But maybe that can really be the subject of a second question when you run into it.

Comment: Since I have marked this post as the answer, I copied the comments that fixed my problem up into the body of the post.